AppBar widget similar to the eBay app in Flutter
enter image description here
I actually wrote the code, but it does not work correctly. The search bar is supposed to be on top of the logo, but that does not happen. The opposite happens. And another addition. The search bar is supposed to shrink in order to fit the width with the icon, but that does not happen. The search bar is below them. –
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          excludeHeaderSemantics: true,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff191919),
          elevation: 0.0,
          expandedHeight: width / 3,
          pinned: true,
          forceMaterialTransparency: true,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            expandedTitleScale: 1.5,
            titlePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            stretchModes: const <StretchMode>[StretchMode.fadeTitle],
            collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 30,
                child: TextField(
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Search on eBay',
                    hintStyle:
                        const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.black,
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(
                      CupertinoIcons.search,
                      size: 20,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    suffixIcon: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {},
                          child: const Icon(
                            CupertinoIcons.mic,
                            size: 20,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            // Add your onTap code here for the camera icon
                          },
                          child:  const Icon(
                            CupertinoIcons.camera,
                            size: 20,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                      ],
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          title: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 8),
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              AppImages.logoImageSvg,
              width: width / 5,
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black, // Background color
                  shape: BoxShape.circle, // Circular shape
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.cart),
                  color: Colors.white, // Icon color to contrast with the black background
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            )

          ],
        ),

      ],
    ),
  ),
);


What's the question here? You only shared your code not the question

I want the code

What's the code? you have already.

I actually wrote the code, but it does not work correctly. The search bar is supposed to be on top of the logo, but that does not happen. The opposite happens. And another addition. The search bar is supposed to shrink in order to fit the width with the icon, but that does not happen. The search bar is below them.

Your code is exactly works as you uploaded image. Uploaded image is your desired result or your result?

Not the result shown in the picture, I want the result as a picture

I have tried your code and it's exactly that you want in image. Can you please clarify your question again?

@NipulRathod See the screenshot Not exactly what is specified there are some errors

You need to increase the expanded height i.e try the below code:
    Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          excludeHeaderSemantics: true,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff191919),
          elevation: 0.0,
          expandedHeight: 500
          pinned: true,
          forceMaterialTransparency: true,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            expandedTitleScale: 1.5,
            titlePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            stretchModes: const <StretchMode>[StretchMode.fadeTitle],
            collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 30,
                child: TextField(
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Search on eBay',
                    hintStyle:
                        const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.black,
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(
                      CupertinoIcons.search,
                      size: 20,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    suffixIcon: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {},
                          child: const Icon(
                            CupertinoIcons.mic,
                            size: 20,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            // Add your onTap code here for the camera icon
                          },
                          child:  const Icon(
                            CupertinoIcons.camera,
                            size: 20,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                      ],
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          title: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 8),
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              AppImages.logoImageSvg,
              width: width / 5,
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black, // Background color
                  shape: BoxShape.circle, // Circular shape
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.cart),
                  color: Colors.white, // Icon color to contrast with the black background
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            )

          ],
        ),

      ],
    ),
  ),
);


See the screenshot Not exactly what is specified there are some errors

did you try the code i shared ?
